# Quotes not properly compiles when using `` and ''

Tags: symbols, quoting, csquotes

I downloaded a latex template for a CV, and in it I tried to apply the usual `` '' syntax for opening and closing quotes. However, they turn out to be one sided ('' is treated as open quote, while it should be closing). Any idea why this might be happening? I also tried `csquotes` but that did not solve it.

The template I am using can be found [here](https://www.sharelatex.com/templates/cv-or-resume/cv-us).

Comment: The font is Palatino, which has distinctive quotes; however opening and closing quotes are different from each other.

Comment: I've tried that and for me it works the `\`\`` way.

Comment: Are you using  `'' ` or `"`? I've tried with `'' ` and it works.